# Is there a way to not expose the content of my play! app routes file

Tags: web-services, routes, playframework

I have a play! app providing web service (set of APIs) to my app running on iPhone. If I access the web service from inside browser by intentionally provide a wrong query, the whole content of the play! app's routes file will be exposed on browser. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Do you run your server in "Production mode"?

Comment: will that help? I guess it'll take sometime for me to flip to production mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That only happens when your application is running in Dev mode. When you switch to Prod mode, routes will no longer be exposed like that.

Useful links:

- http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/guide11#aSettingtheapplicationinPRODmodea
- http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/main#lifecycle
- http://playframework.wordpress.com/2011/03/05/playframework-dev-mode-never-use-in-production/

Comment: in my application.conf file, I have both application.mode=dev and also %prod.application.mode=prod, should I simply # out the dev one? what does the %prod for?

Comment: Now I have only %prod.application.mode=prod left, but still when I try with a incorrect query, the contents of the routes will be shown. I tried removing %prod., then I got 503 (service not available).

Comment: so basically, what i observed is that %prod.application.mode=prod setting somehow doesn't work with my app. i can still kill the app remotely from browser. what else could be missing/wrong?

Comment: by reading the articles that you shared, it does seem that setting prod mode should solve the problem. But it somehow doesn't happen to my case. So I created another SO question that got answered at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248456/play-application-conf-content-thats-bit-of-confusing