# play! application.conf content that's bit of confusing

Tags: configuration, playframework, configuration-files

I am using play 1.2.3, in the application.conf, it has the following settings. What does each setting mean? It seems both are turned on, which one will take the priority? And also, if I remove the first setting (DEV mode), I don't get the PROD mode when run the app, am I missing anything?

```
# Application mode
# ~~~~~
# Set to dev to enable instant reloading and other development help.
# Otherwise set to prod.
application.mode=dev
%prod.application.mode=prod
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`application.mode` is run by default.

the other one runs when you are running with a prod mode switch. For example, if you start your application like the following

```
play run myapp --%prod
```

it will use the `prod.application.mode` config.

This means that you can define many different configurations for certain environments. For more information, check out this information on the [Play documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/ids).

Comment: sorry but which switch is the prod mode switch?

Comment: I think my edit with the link etc, crossed with your comment.